# error al crear un nuevo usuario en MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mariadb, macos

anteriormente he estado trabajando con mariadb en workbench con el puerto 3306 y ahora que quise instalar mysql de automatico se conecto al puerto 3306. ya intente cambiarlo al puerto 3307 pero al hacer un examen en utilidad de red me aparece que mysql esta en el 3306 y que el 3307 ya esta ocupado por no se que  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

intente entonces creando una coneccion en workbench con el puerto 3306 (que se supone que es en el que esta mysql) y ya estando adentro quiero crear un nuevo usuario pero me marca este error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]